# Proving that Every Full Prefix-Free Language is Maximal

Tags: formal-languages

I'm practicing a problem where I need to prove that every full prefix-free language is maximal.

I know a prefix-free language A is *maximal* if it is not a proper subset of any prefix-free language, where a prefix-free language is *full* if,

$$\sum_{x\in A} 2^{-|x|} = 1$$

Furthermore, I know that a language A ⊆ {0, 1}* is [*prefix-free*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) if no element of A is a prefix of any other element of A and that the [*Kraft inequality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality) says that for every prefix-free language A,

$$\sum_{x\in A} 2^{-|x|} \leqslant 1$$

I'm pretty sure that a full prefix free language is maximal, since it belongs to the maximal prefix-free set. I don't know, however, how to formally prove this. Should I be doing induction with Kraft's Inequality and with what I know about the relationship between maximal and prefix-free sets?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a full prefix code. Suppose that $A$ is not maximal. Then there is some word $u \notin A$ such that $B = A \cup \{u\}$ is a prefix code. It follows that
$$
\sum_{x\in B} 2^{-|x|} \leqslant 1
$$ 
and hence 
$$
\sum_{x\in A} 2^{-|x|} < 1
$$ 
a contradiction. Thus $A$ is maximal.

N.B. The bible for this type of question is the book [1]

[1] J. Berstel, D. Perrin and C. Reutenauer, *Codes and automata*, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications, 129. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2010. xiv+619 pp. ISBN: 978-0-521-88831-8